# Draw a path from the bottom left corner of a div to a certain destination

Tags: javascript, html, css, responsive

Sorry for the vague title. I am not sure how to express this.
So i want to draw a line from the bottom left (or right) corner of the div to a certain point in an image. What is the best responsive way to achieve this? I drew an example here.

[image]

So my guess is with pseudo elements like ::after but how do i get that bend and how do i keep it responsive? If somebody got some site examples i would be grateful aswell.

Comment: this looks like svg not css

Answer (score 0):

Canvas may be overkill, but here's how you might do it:

The CSS is simple. You'll need a container element, a canvas element and the image description element.

```
#vegetable-image {
    /* container */
    position: relative;
}
#vegetable-image > canvas {
    /* This contains your image. The width and height is set in the canvas element */
    background:url(vegetables.jpg);
    background-size:cover;
}
#vegetable-image > div {
    /* style for the element from which you're drawing the line */
    position: absolute;
    top: 20px;
    left: 20px;
    width: 300px;
    height: 200px;
    background: white;
    padding: 10px;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="vegetable-image">
    <canvas width="600" height="300"></canvas>
    <div><h3>Eat eat eat</h3><p>lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p></div>
</div>
```

The JavaScript gets the canvas and description box, calculates the bottom right corner of the box (minus 10px so you don't see the end of the line), and draws the line. The first `lineTo` command, `ctx.lineTo(380,260);`, contains the coordinates that you want to draw the line to. The second one right after, 
`ctx.lineTo(380,280);`, draws to a point 20px lower to give that bend.

```
var vegetable = document.getElementById("vegetable-image");
var canvas = vegetable.getElementsByTagName("canvas")[0];
var tag = vegetable.getElementsByTagName("div")[0];
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
var lineStartLeft = tag.offsetLeft + tag.offsetWidth - 10; // 10 px back from right edge
var lineStartTop = tag.offsetTop + tag.offsetHeight - 10; // 10 px back from bottom

ctx.beginPath();
ctx.moveTo(lineStartLeft,lineStartTop);
ctx.lineTo(380,260);
ctx.lineTo(380,280);
ctx.lineWidth = 10;  // line thickness
ctx.strokeStyle = '#ffffff';  // line colour
ctx.stroke();
```

To be responsive you might set a css media query to set the description box position to relative, and disable the canvas line drawing when on mobile.

Comment: Wow i appreciate your time and effort. I will take a look into this as soon as possible.